# Python3 error : AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to run a script in python3 (tried with 3.7.4 and 3.8.0) which uses `urllib.request` and `urllib.error`.

I tried importing in the following ways:

```
import urllib
```

and

```
from urllib import request
```

but in both the above cases I get error:

```
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'
```

I haven't installed anything related to `urllib` as it comes with python3

Please suggest how should this be imported, thanks!

Comment: (a) Are you _entirely_ sure you're using Python 3? (b) Do you have a file called `urllib.py`?

Comment: (a) yes (b) no , `import urllib.request` worked for me, thanks!

Comment: "`import urllib.request` worked for me"—that seems unlikely considering the error you were getting. Voting to close as "not reproducible".

Answer (score 6):

Worked with following import:

```
import urllib.request
```

Answer (score 6):

Since urllib is a folder and request is a file inside urllib, you should use:

```
import urllib.request as request
```